# Making org-agenda-list hide items scheduled for the future

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use the `org-mode` weekly/daily agenda and want to be able to use the `SCHEDULED` keyword to hide items until the scheduled time comes up. I don't want to think about them until then. How can I set up `org-agenda-list` to do this?

This is the list of agenda items, not the TODO list. I already have `org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled` set to `future`. It does not help.

Comment: We must be misunderstanding your question, because what you're seeking is the default behavior of org mode AFAIK. I've made a simple example of this (using OrgMode version 6.33x). With four items, one with no scheduled date, one scheduled yesterday, one scheduled today, and one scheduled tomorrow, I open agenda list and toggle to day view and go to today (keystrokes "v d ."), I see the item scheduled yesterday (with Sched 2x to indicate it was scheduled yesterday), and I see the item scheduled today. Both the unscheduled and future scheduled item [do not appear here](http://imgur.com/9SPF8hY)

Comment: However, if they also have near term deadlines, they will still show up even if scheduled in the future. Any chance some of the items that you don't want to appear have deadlines? If so, there are some other variables/properties I can point you to in order to manipulate that.

Answer (score 9):

Set

```
(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled 'future)
```

and

```
(setq org-agenda-tags-todo-honor-ignore-options t)
```

Comment: This is the list of agenda items, not the TODO list. I already have `org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled` set to `future`. It does not help.

Comment: Missing option. Edited my answer.

Comment: That does not fix this problem. Again, it is the list of agenda items, not the global TODO list.

Comment: By looking up the help on the variable `org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled` by doing `C-h v` the docs state it *does* affect the global todo list: "This applies when creating the global todo list." It also says: "See also the variable `org-agenda-tags-todo-honor-ignore-options` if you want to make his option also apply to the tags-todo list." I hope this helps.

Comment: They said NOT the TODO list, but rather the agenda view.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably get what you want using org-modes confusing set of parameters but it's probably just easier creating a custom filter function

```lisp
  (defun my/org-skip-function (part)
    "Partitions things to decide if they should go into the agenda '(agenda future-scheduled done)"
    (let* ((skip (save-excursion (org-entry-end-position)))
           (dont-skip nil)
           (scheduled-time (org-get-scheduled-time (point)))
           (result
            (or (and scheduled-time
                     (time-less-p (current-time) scheduled-time)
                     'future-scheduled)  ; This is scheduled for a future date
                (and (org-entry-is-done-p) ; This entry is done and should probably be ignored
                     'done)
                'agenda)))                 ; Everything else should go in the agenda
      (if (eq result part) dont-skip skip)))
   (setq org-agenda-skip-function '(my/org-skip-function 'agenda))
```

If you want other filters just add them to the `or`-block with a different tag.

Comment: How do you modify this, so you can filter out future days but still see the scheduled items for the current day? I was thinking just add 12 or 24 hours to the current time so it shows the current or next 24 hours scheduled activities. what is the best way to do this? I wasn't sure how to add 12 hours to a time.

Comment: Adding 24 hours to the current time can be done like this `(time-add (current-time) (* 24 60 60))`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date t)`

From http://orgmode.org/manual/Global-TODO-list.html